# how can l implement my android app for both admin and clients like home with other screen different for admin and clients in same app

Tags: android, android-volley

anybody tell me how to implement my android app that will works for both admin and client because admin has difeernt screens and layout and clients has differnt Scrrens layout .how could i solved please tell me .
i am working on android aand using webservices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like @Jas said or there is another way.

You can do it with one activity and two different layouts. One for Admin, another for Client. Depends on user type inflate respective layout by `setContentView()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use different Activity classes for different users. Suppose if your user is Admin, show an Activity with UI required for admin and if your user is Client, show an Activity with UI required for Client.